# Как реализовать таймер с асинхронным вызовом?

Tags: linux, c, таймер

Интересует как реализовать таймер с асинхронным вызовом через промежуток времени на си.
Вот, допустим, таймер на javascript задается:

```
setTimeout(func, 1000);
```

или на boost::asio:

```
boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
t.async_wait(&print);
```

Интересует как такое же реализовать на си. Т.е. задаем таймер, делаем полезную работу, а через некоторое время срабатывает сигнал или как-то по-другому асинхронно оповещаем. Просто тупо делать задержку это не то, а именно вызвать через какой-то промежуток времени, не приостанавливая работу до этого момента. Хотя бы сам принцип, что использовать, `eventfd`, сигналы или что-то еще.

Comment: linux? pthreads

Comment: поток, под таймер? это нереальный оверхед имхо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы правильно думаете, используйте сигналы, вызванные с помощью `alarm()` или `setitimer()`. Системный вызов `setitimer()` является обобщением вызова `alarm()`.

```
/* Обработчик сигнала*/
void catch_alarm(int sig)
{
  printf("Do stuff...");
}

/* Устанавливаем обработчик для SIGALRM */
signal (SIGALRM, catch_alarm);

/* Ставим таймер на 2 секунды */
alarm(2);
```

Вообще, каждый процесс имеет три независимых таймера:

- Таймер реального времени, отсчитывающий прошедшее время. Этот таймер отправляет сигнал `SIGALRM` процессу, когда он истекает.
- Виртуальный таймер, который измеряет только время выполнения самого процесса. Этот таймер отправляет сигнал `SIGVTALRM` процессу, когда он истекает.
- Таймер профилирования, который измеряет время выполнения самого процесса и время, проведённое в ожидании завершения системных вызовов. Этот таймер отправляет сигнал `SIGPROF` процессу, когда он истекает.

Вы можете установить только один таймер каждого типа в любой момент времени. Если вы установите таймер, который еще не истек, этот таймер просто сбрасывается на новое значение.

Comment: хм, не слышал про такие таймеры... а вы не в курсе: boost::asio::deadline_timer использует этот самый alarm?

Comment: @xperious не использует.

Comment: а не знаете тогда что там под капотом?

Comment: @xperious вроде у них там свой какой-то механизм, гляньте [тут](https://github.com/boostorg/asio)